# GET is working but POST is not working on Docker

Tags: django, docker, nginx, nginx-config

The application is on Django configured with Docker. GET requests are working fine. But the POST requests are not working. I am adding the nginx.conf file below for the reference.

The POST request is necessary for authentication.

```
upstream app_server {
  server djangoapp:8000 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  listen 80;
  server_name samplewebsite.com;
  root /opt/djangoapp/src/samplewebsite/samplewebsite;
  index index.html;

  server_tokens off;

 location / {
   try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
 }

  location /media  {
    alias /opt/djangoapp/src/media/;
  }

  location /static {
    alias /opt/djangoapp/src/static/;
  }

  location /api/ {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_pass http://app_server/;
  }

  location /admin/ {
    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_set_header Host $host;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Host $server_name;
    proxy_pass http://app_server/admin/;
  }

    client_max_body_size 128m;
}
```

The response of the POST request is Error code 405.

Let me know if I need to add more information to the question.

Comment: What do you mean by *"But the POST requests are not working."* ? What response you have got?

Comment: It is error code 405. @ArakkalAbu

Comment: I am not sure why did you add the nginx config instead of your Django code. Show your urls.py as well as views.

Comment: Which path are you POSTing to?  Do the requests reach the backend, and does the backend return 200 or 405 (or something else)?  If you send the same request directly to the backend service, bypassing the Nginx proxy, does it work?